# Can I browse by Artist, then by Album, then by Song in the Xbox Music app for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, music, media-player, xbox-music

Most music players allow you to browse like this:

- Select an artist from the list of artists
- Select an album from a list of the artist's albums
- Play the album or view its songs

In the Xbox Music app, I see the following way to browse:

- By album. The albums are not grouped by artist.
- By artist. When you select an artist, you see all of that artist's songs. They are *ordered* by album, but you can't say for example "Play all of the songs in this album".
- By song. Again, they are *ordered* by album, but you cannot select/play individual albums.
- By playlist

Is there any way to use the traditional Artist->Album->Song workflow in Xbox Music?

Edit: To clarify, I am talking about "Xbox Music" on Windows 8, not on Xbox.

Comment: Video game console questions are off topic at superuser http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: It's not about a video game console. The Metro-style music player app in Windows 8 is called "Xbox Music".

Comment: Aah...my mistake then

Comment: And that is a stupid name for them to choose as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sort of...**

You can enter your music, and rather than select `artists`, select `albums`. If you then change the `arranged by` setting to `artist` you get something similar to what you're looking for:

[image]

Selecting an album will then give you a tracklisting:

[image]

From there you can select to play all, or select individual tracks to play. It doesn't seem you can navigate in quite the way you expected though.

Comment: Close enough. I was hoping for a more compact listing (just artist names), but this more or less meets my needs.